# GNOME password not the same as logon password

Tags: gnome, password, authentication

When I am trying to perform various tasks from within GNOME, I get this "Authentication Required" dialog:

[image: Authentication Required]

I type the exact same string, that I use to unlock from the lock screen, but I get access denied every time. Could this have something to do with the fact that I've set up sudo to be passwordless?  If not, is the "Administrator" a clue? (that is *not* my username)

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, it's asking for "Administrator" password, which is the root password and not yours. This probably happens because of passwordless sudo, although I'm not 100% sure.

You could try restoring sudo to its normal behaviour and see if that solves the problem, or just set a password for root and use that when asked.

To change root password, simply open a terminal and run

```
sudo passwd root
```

and type your desired password. This is normally not recommended because of security reasons, but given that you use no password on sudo, I supose that's not a problem for you. If you want to disable root account again, just run

```
sudo passwd --lock root
```

and it will be disabled.